# my own interpose function as an exercise

Tags: clojure

I'm resolving a 4Clojure exercise, this exercise asks you to build your own interpose function. My answer follows:

```
(fn my-interpose 
  ([separator input] (my-interpose separator input nil))
  ([separator input result] 
    (if 
      (empty? input) 
      (reverse (rest result))
      (my-interpose separator (rest input) (cons separator (cons (first input) result))))))
```

I'm doing these exercises to learn the language as I read a Clojure book. I will like to know the opinion about my code of people with an experience in the language. Could I avoid the reverse call? Are there any conventions I'm breaking hardly with this kind of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is a good proper starting point :). Excellent work.

Starting with what you have you may want to:

- Replace your recursive call with a call to `recur` because as written it will hit a stack overflow

  ```
  (defn foo [stuff]
    (dostuff ... )
    (foo (rest stuff)))
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
  (defn foo [stuff]
    (dostuff ...)
    (recur (rest stuff)))
  ```

  to avoid blowing the stack. this then often becomes:

  `(map dostuff stuff)`
- Replace the recustion entirely with the `for` function

  ```
  (for [a one-list b another-list]
    (dont-give-away-the-answer))
  ```

Comment: this formats correctly in the preview and not when I save the edit? How do I fix this formatting?

Comment: Opened my mind with the 'map' usage, It's so obvious and at the same time so important.

Comment: @amalloy thanks for fixing the formatting :) I just needed to use indents and not <pre> or <code> tags?

Comment: Yeah, getting code blocks into bulleted lists in markdown is a serious pain. I'm pretty sure it's possible to do it some way closer to what you were doing, but this is what I know. Also, I replaced your <code> tags with \` marks because that's just so much easier to type.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can avoid the reverse call,

```
(defn my-interpose [sep coll]
  (when (seq coll)
    (lazy-cat [(first coll) sep]
              (my-interpose sep (rest coll)))))
```

as arthur suggest you can use recur in order to not to blow the stack but 99% of the time you don't need it.

EDIT:

This is a bit cleaner,

```
(defn my-interpose [sep coll]
  (if-let [[first & rest] coll]
    (lazy-cat [first sep] (my-interpose sep rest))))
```

Comment: wow! lots to learn here, thanks! Could you please help me understand the if-let part.
I mean, what condition are you evaluating for the if? I guess if you can't divide the collection into first and rest then false is returned?

Comment: The condition he is testing is `coll`. If coll is nil, then the if fails, and nothing is `let`'ed.

Answer (score 2):

Got to various answers using mapcat and for but in the end I found this:

```
#(rest (interleave (repeat %1) %2))
```

Where the first argument is the separator and the second is the collection. Just posting this answer for pure curiosity of other Clojure noobs like me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, trying to rely on lower-level lisp or scheme-like functions.

```
(defn my-interpose[sep coll]                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  (letfn [(f [c]                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            (when-not (empty? c)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
              (cons sep (cons (first c)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                              (f (next c))))))]                                                                                                                                                                                             
    (next (f coll))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use *map*

```
(defn my-interpose [sep coll]
  (rest (apply concat (map #(vector sep %) coll))))
```

or a directly a *reduce* and compute the answer as you go

```
(defn my-interpose [sep coll]
  (rest (reduce #(conj %1 sep %2) [] coll)))
```

The idea behind this is to compute a sequence like `(sep x0 sep x1 sep x2 ... sep xn)` and then skip the first element to get `(x0 sep x1 sep x2 ... xn)`.

Answer (score 0):

Using just `reduce and conj:`

```
(defn my-interpose [sep a-seq]
  (if (empty? a-seq)
    a-seq
    (reduce (fn [e1 e2] (if (empty? e1)
                          (conj e1 e2)
                          (conj e1 sep e2))) [] a-seq)))
```